# Alternative for ShellExecuteW in 64-bit Windows 7, 8

Tags: delphi, windows-8, delphi-xe, windows-7-x64, shellexecute

I create application for 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

```
var
Form1: TForm1;
FilePath : string;

implementation

uses ShellAPI;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FilePath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
.........................

procedure TForm1.MenuItem4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  path_to_handbook : WideString;
begin
  case language of
    $0019 : path_to_handbook := FilePath+'help\handbook-ru.pdf'; // Russian
    $0009 : path_to_handbook := FilePath+'help\handbook-en.pdf'; // English
  end;
  ShellExecuteW(Handle, nil, PWideChar(path_to_handbook), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Function ShellExecuteW in 64-bit Windows 7 or 8 not work!

How can I solve it problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Do you get an error message? Is there an exception or access violation?

Comment: I can not upload the help file from click at menuitem. Manager Task show two process Adobe Reader. Descends nothing. Help files do not open. Error messages are not present!

Comment: `ShellExecuteW` is a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and therefore has a return value. What does it return?

Comment: Clearly, if Adobe Reader starts running then `ShellExecute()` did its job correctly. Adobe is at fault instead. Make sure the `.pdf` file extension is configured correctly in the Registry under 64-bit, and that your version of Adobe does not have any known bugs with opening files under 64-bit. Also, why are you using `WideString` instead of `UnicodeString`?

Comment: In other programs Adobe had been working normal. WideString or UnicodeString not solve my problem. Why function ShellExecute() create two streams Adobe Reader in the Manager Task?

Comment: Your code is fine. ShellExecute works fine. Don't use WideString, use plain string. Use PChar rather than PWideChar. Use ShellExecute rather than ShellExecuteW. But your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my own configuration, when compiling with Win64 as target.

Please try:

```
ShellExecuteW(Handle, 'open', PWideChar(path_to_handbook), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I mean, explicitly setting `'open'` instead of `nil` to the `lpOperation` parameter. Seems to work better on my side, for Win64 applications.

Comment: Passing nil fornthe verb is fine. The docs say: *The default verb is used, if available. If not, the "open" verb is used. If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb listed in the registry.*

Comment: @David, so what if there's no verb for 64-bit registry node ? Which verb is the "first one" listed then ? Who can guarantee that it's `open` ?

Comment: @TLama The shell file associations are held in a shared part of the registry. No redirection. It's sad that this answer is upvoted when it is just FUD.

Comment: @David, ah, of course. That makes sense. I was thinking about executables instead of documents that needs to have associations. There's no bitness involved for documents. [not voted in this thread]

Comment: @TLama Right. The COM registry is of course redirected. Because of bitness issues. HKCR is a virtual key. It merges HKLM\Software\Classes and HKCU\Software\Classes, both of which are shared. The subkeys, Software\Classes\CLSID are the COM registry and they are redirected. Back on Vista, the two \Software\Classes keys were redirected and reflected but reflection died with Windows 7 (thankfully). Even so, a proper installation would not exhibit behaviour differences due to bitness because redirection/reflection typically behaves the same as shared.

Comment: I'm beginning asking myself why I spend time in here. All this Delphi StackOverflow is a real troll forest! I posted this answer because I add the issue, just like the OP, and AFAIR, using 'open' fixed it in my case.

Comment: Your post is FUD. You mis-diagnosed the fault. ShellExecute is the same on 32 bit OS as it is on 64 bit OS. The same for 32 and 64 bit process.

Comment: It does not behave the same. I had the same problem than the OP. So it depends on the context. Period. Did U try to reproduce it?

Comment: Yes. Passing nil works fine here. You have shown no evidence for the claim that 32 bit OS differs from 64 bit OS.

Comment: Did you test it with a .pdf file, and Acrobat Reader? I've seen the problem on my own computer. And fixed it by using 'open'.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your call to `ShellExecute`, and `ShellExecute` works perfectly adequately on 64 bit Windows. There is no need for an alternative to `ShellExecute` since it works.

I would probably write the code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.MenuItem4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  langstr: string;
  path_to_handbook: string;
begin
  case language of
  $0019:
    langstr := 'ru';
  $0009: 
    langstr := 'en';
  else
    raise ESomeExceptionClass.Create('Unrecognised language');
  end;
  path_to_handbook := Format(
    '%shelp\handbook-%s.pdf', 
    [ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName), langstr]
  );

  // mainly for debugging purposes
  if not FileExists(path_to_handbook) then
    raise ESomeExceptionClass.CreateFmt(
      'File not found: %s', 
      [path_to_handbook]
    );

  ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar(path_to_handbook), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

I suppose it is conceivable that your language switching code is not finding a recognised language and your code just ignores that failure because you don't have an `else` clause in your case statement.

One other possibility is that your executable is under `C:\Windows\System32` and so your path is subject to the file system redirector. That could certainly confuse matters but surely you are not committing such a grave error as to put your executable in the system directory.

But assuming that `path_to_handbook` is the correct path of a PDF file, if your code fails then the issue is the Acrobat file association rather than your code. In other words, the problem is environmental.

Comment: ESomeExceptionClass.Create - compiler of Delphi XE4 give me error. Is it error? Thank you

Comment: Supply whatever exception class you want to use. I'm making the point that you did not write code to cater for the case statement not assigning `path_to_handbook`. You need to be thinking about what the code means rather than just copying it without understanding. The code is yours remember.

Comment: I used "raise Exception.Create" and "raise Exception.CreateFmt". Is it correctly? Thank you.

Comment: That will do fine for the purpose of testing

Comment: All the same, when I extract the help files of the ManagerTask running two processes Adobe Reader.

Comment: What were you expecting? Read the final paragraph of my answer again. Your problem is environmental. Well, I am assuming that you did not put your exe in the system directory did you? What is the value of `path_to_handbook`?

Comment: I did not put my exe in the system directory. The myprogram exe in C:\Program Files\My Program\myprogram.exe and Adobe Reader in C:\Program Files(x86)\Adobe\.... The value of path_to_handbook is absolute rightly - C:\Program Files\My Program\help\handbook.pdf! Where is error? Thanks

Comment: Like I said, the problem would appear to be environmental.

Comment: It is a pity, what even there is no assumption how to solve a problem. Thanks

Comment: How can we solve a fault that exists only on your machine? My answer is telling you that ShellExecute works and that your diagnosis is wrong. You diagnosed the fault as being that ShellExecute does not work on win 64. Well, it does.

Comment: AFAIK ShellExecute() does not work the same as in 32 bit mode, in respect to the lpOperation parameter, which should not be left to nil, but explicitly to 'open'. As expected by the official MSDN documentation, by the way. See my answer.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Read the docs. They say: *The default verb is used, if available. If not, the "open" verb is used. If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb listed in the registry.* There is no difference between 32 and 64 bit in the treatment of the shell verbs thatnInam aware of. Unless you have evidence then your comment is FUD.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Trolls off, please. It works in my case. Endpoint.

Comment: @Arnaud Don't you want to understand why? Or is trial and error good enough?

Comment: @Andriy - Have you executed a text file for instance, to see if ShellExecute works correctly?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm so tired I just want it to work. And by setting 'Open', it works in all cases, for me. It may be a problem of Acrobat Reader registration, or whatever. I've no time to debugg third party applications. Just making it work as expected, with a correct 'Open' parameter, and not relying on a default behavior on nil, sounds fair enough.

Comment: @Arnaud I was objecting to your statement that there is a behaviour difference between 32 and 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

I use ShellExecuteEx as follows , it works on my Windows 7

```
procedure TAboutBox.WinexecAndWait(exeCutefile,paramstring:string);
var
   SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
   ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
   if pos('http:',lowercase(executeFile))>0 then begin
     laAnswer.Caption:=executeFile;
     close;
   end;
   screen.Cursor:=crHourglass;
   FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0) ;
   SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo) ;
   with SEInfo do begin
     fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;    
     Wnd := Application.Handle;
     lpFile := PChar(ExecuteFile) ;
        { ParamString can contain the application parameters. }
     lpParameters := PChar(ParamString) ;
        { StartInString specifies the name of the working directory. 
    If ommited, the current directory is used. }
        // lpDirectory := PChar(StartInString) ;
     nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
   end;
   if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then begin
     repeat
       Application.ProcessMessages;
       GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode) ;
     until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or  Application.Terminated;
   end else begin
     ShowMessage('Dji n''a nén polou fé çu ki fåt aveu '+executeFile)     ;
   end;
  screen.Cursor:=crDefault;
end;
```